# Using for loop instead of foreach throws an error

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I am using a simple for loop to print field names of a table and it didn't work but the same code when I wrote using foreach loop it worked perfectly fine. I am a bit confused as to what might have caused it. Please help me find where I went wrong with the coding.

Code using foreach-loop:

```
$data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `address` order by $id $sort");
echo "<tr>";
    $field=mysqli_fetch_fields($data);
    foreach ($field as $val) {
        echo "<th><a href='sort_table_data_asc_desc.php?fn=$val->name &ord=$sort'>$val->name</a></th>";
    }
echo "</tr>";
```

Output: as requested

[image]

Code using for-loop:

```
$data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `address` order by $id $sort");
$col=mysqli_num_fields($data);
echo "<tr>";
    $field=mysqli_fetch_fields($data);
    for ($i=0;$i<$col;$i++) {
        echo "<th><a href='sort_table_data_asc_desc.php?fn=$field->name &ord=$sort'>$field->name</a></th>";
    }
echo "</tr>";
```

Output: as requested

[image]

Comment: Can you edit to show the expected output and what you actually got?

Comment: @Nick added the images as per your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_fields` returns an array of the fields, so you need to reference the array element when accessing the values

```
echo "<th><a href='sort_table_data_asc_desc.php?fn={$field[$i]->name}&ord=$sort'>{$field[$i]->name}</a></th>";
```

As you can see, I'm using `$field[$i]` at each point you access the fields coming back from `mysqli_fetch_fields`

Comment: I did what you said but it throws an error,  "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: I've updated it to include {} round the field, it makes the field itself clearer, can you try that

Comment: I've just tried it on a table I have and it works OK, have you changed both references to `$field`?

Comment: Yes @Nigel, I changed both the references in the URL as you said but it didn't work on my end.

Comment: If the error is giving a particular line of code that's showing the error, can you make sure that is in the code on your original question.

Comment: I get your point @Nigel, looked into documentation, it is only logical to use $field[$i]->name. Thanks a lot for your help!